# jQuery Mobile with CSS3 responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm working ona responsive web application and i need some touch events. So I added the jQuery Mobile framework. Now, all my layout is ruined, because jQuery Mobile adds some css styles and divs in my html markup.

Can I use the touch and swipe event of jQuery Mobile without altering (at all) my html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked for me, you can find the javascript files you need in [this repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js)

You can download the things you need, without downloading the whole package. I downloaded just the event related files, and I used them without altering my html markup. It's not the best solution, but it's working for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I don't think what you are asking is possible.

How about coding the CSS3 animations by hand, and using Zepto.js for the touch/swipe events? Zepto.js is uses the same syntax as jQuery, but is much smaller (and only compatible with the latest browsers including mobile browsers). It also includes touch/swipe events.

Comment: i need support for windows phone, and i saw that zepto does not offer support for ie.